# How to combine aggregation, filter, and by in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I need to aggregate all my columns, but only if their values are 1, and group by an another columns.

Here is how I could perform this, step by step, i.e. column by column, from *foo* to *out*, the expected output.

```
set.seed(123)
foo <- data.table(id = rep(LETTERS[1:10], each = 10),
                  code = sample(c(111, 222, 333, 444), 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x1 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x2 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x3 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x4 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x5 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                  x6 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))



f1 <- foo[x1 == 1, .(x1 = uniqueN(code)), by = id]
f2 <- foo[x2 == 1, .(x2 = uniqueN(code)), by = id]
f3 <- foo[x3 == 1, .(x3 = uniqueN(code)), by = id]

setkey(f1, id)
setkey(f2, id)
setkey(f3, id)

out <- f1[f2,][f3,]
```

I'm sure there is an elegant and fast way to do this in `data.table`, maybe with a function and the `.SDcols` parameter, right?

But I can't find it...

Many thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `.SD` and `.SDcols`:

```
foo[,lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(code[x==1])), .SDcols = x1:x3, by = id]

    id x1 x2 x3
 1:  A  3  3  2
 2:  B  4  4  4
 3:  C  2  2  3
 4:  D  4  3  3
 5:  E  4  4  3
 6:  F  1  3  3
 7:  G  3  2  2
 8:  H  4  2  3
 9:  I  3  3  3
10:  J  3  2  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
foo %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(across(x1:x3, ~ n_distinct(code[.==1])))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   id       x1    x2    x3
# * <chr> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 A         3     3     2
# 2 B         4     4     4
# 3 C         2     2     3
# 4 D         4     3     3
# 5 E         4     4     3
# 6 F         1     3     3
# 7 G         3     2     2
# 8 H         4     2     3
# 9 I         3     3     3
#10 J         3     2     2
```

---

Or can use `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
collap(slt(foo, id, x1:x3), ~ id, fNdistinct)
```

Comment: Thanks too ! I will run several tests on hundreds of columns, but it seems to be faster than the data.table solution (?).

Comment: @Discus23 i don't know if it is faster or not.  What is your take on it

Comment: off topic, but how do i create hundreds of x var in my foo reprex ?

Comment: @Discus23 you can just change the `across(matches('^x\\d+$'), ~ .`

Comment: Oh non, misunderstanding ... I meant in my foo data, if I want to create x1 to x100 ?

Comment: @Discus23 you meant creating a reproducible example with 100 columns

Comment: @Discus23 that is easier wtih `matrix(sample(0:1, 100 * 10, replace = TRUE), ncol = 100, dimnames  = list(NULL, paste0('x', 1:100)))`

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option using `duplicated`(but I think `uniqueN` by [@Waldi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67607271/12158757) is more straightforward)

```
> foo[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(!duplicated(code[x == 1]))), id, .SDcols = x1:x3]
    id x1 x2 x3
 1:  A  3  3  2
 2:  B  4  4  4
 3:  C  2  2  3
 4:  D  4  3  3
 5:  E  4  4  3
 6:  F  1  3  3
 7:  G  3  2  2
 8:  H  4  2  3
 9:  I  3  3  3
10:  J  3  2  2
```